# Extract nested data from XML as data frame in R

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing, xmlnodelist

I am trying to extract data from an XML file, sample structure below:

```
<pwx creator="PerfPRO" version="1.0">
<workout>
<athlete></athlete>
<title></title>
<sportType>Bike</sportType>
<cmt></cmt>
<device id=""></device>
<time>2016-01-19T08:01:00</time>
<summarydata>
    <beginning>0</beginning>
    <duration>3600.012</duration>
</summarydata>
<segment>
    <summarydata>
        <beginning>0</beginning>
        <duration>120</duration>
    </summarydata>
</segment>
<segment>
    <summarydata>
        <beginning>120</beginning>
        <duration>120</duration>
    </summarydata>
</segment>
<segment>
    <summarydata>
        <beginning>240</beginning>
        <duration>120</duration>
    </summarydata>
</segment>
```

I would like to access the data in the 'segment' blocks (both beginning and duration) ideally as a data frame. There are numerous segment blocks.

I have tried numerous things and still can't seem to extract it, all I get is an empty list. Here is what I have done (pwx is the file name):

```
xmlData <- xmlInternalTreeParse(pwx, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
xmltop = xmlRoot(XMLdata)

d <- xpathSApply(doc = xmlData, path = "//pwx/workout/segment/summarydata/beginning", fun = xmlValue)
```

I can also seem to access all the segments through:

```
segment <- xmltop[[1]]["segment"]
```

but can't seem to get the values. I have tried numerous variations on the above.

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks.

edit:

```
> summary(xmlData)
$nameCounts

    cad        dist          hr         pwr      sample         spd  timeoffset   beginning 
   3274        3274        3274        3274        3274        3274        3274          16 


duration summarydata     segment     athlete         cmt      device        make       model 
         16          16          15           1           1           1           1           1 
       name         pwx   sportType        time       title     workout 
          1           1           1           1           1           1 

$numNodes
[1] 22992
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's some raw `xml2` processing with a little `purrr` thrown in:

```
library(xml2)
library(purrr)

nodes <- xml_find_all(doc, ".//segment/summarydata")

map_df(nodes, function(x) {
  kids <- xml_children(x)
  setNames(as.list(type.convert(xml_text(kids))), xml_name(kids))
})

## Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
## 
##   beginning duration
##       (int)    (int)
## 1         0      120
## 2       120      120
## 3       240      120
```

Answer (score 3):

You should check out `rvest`.  The following may not be the most elegant way to use it, but it works.

```
some_xml <- paste0(your_xml,'</workout></pwx>') # your example plus end of data to complete

library('rvest')
some_xml %>% read_xml %>% xml_nodes('summarydata')  -> nodes
nodes %>% xml_nodes('beginning') %>% xml_text -> beginning
nodes %>% xml_nodes('duration') %>% xml_text -> duration
data.frame(beginning, duration, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#   beginning duration
# 1         0 3600.012
# 2         0      120
# 3       120      120
# 4       240      120
```

Comment: I added the ending line to the original question, just fyi.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all who replied and offered an answer. I couldn't get the suggested answers to work as they are above (possibly my own failings).

For completeness and reference I managed to get this to work:

```
pwx <- "myfile.pwx"
xmlData <- xmlInternalTreeParse(pwx, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
xmltop = xmlRoot(xmlData)
nodes <- getNodeSet(xmltop, '//as:summarydata', namespaces = c(as=xmlNamespace(xmltop)))
df <-xmlToDataFrame(nodes)
```

Outputs:

```
     beginning duration
1          0 3600.012
2          0      120
3        120      120
4        240      120
5        360      120
6        480      600
7       1080      180
8       1260      300
9       1560      300
10      1860      180
11      2040      300
12      2340      300
13      2640      180
14      2820      300
15      3120      300
16      3420  180.015
```

Thanks,

M